# ag-grid: change cache block size and do the requests with the new cache block size

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

So I've just implemented the Server Side Row model.

By default, ag-grid does requests asking 100 rows.

I want this size to be taken from a dropdown, like this:

```
<select id="cache-block-size" onchange="setCacheBlockSize()">
      <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
```

How should the setCacheBlockSize function look so it will do the requests with this new size?

```
function setCacheBlockSize() {
    var e = document.getElementById("cache-block-size");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    gridOptions.api.gridOptionsWrapper.setProperty('cacheBlockSize', value);
    //refresh the grid so it uses the new block size
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

agGrid only refresh(init) datasource after set. So the `cacheBlockSize` in the same.

You should set the datasource again after the change of cacheBlockSize.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck